# The best way to store User information in Sessions?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a question regarding the best way to store the Current logged in User's information. The way I see it, is that I have two options:

1) After the user is authenticated, instantiate a User object, and fill that object with the User's data all at once (from a Database). Then serialise that object into a SESSION variable, and keep de-serialising it every time I want to query that object for information.

2) Store just the User's ID in the Session and query the Database each time I need a piece of information pertaining to the Logged In user (Probably by way of some static class method).

Which method would be regarded as 'best practice'? Or is neither recommended, and I should go with a different approach altogether?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on many factors. For example, should changes to the user data propagate immediately to all sessions? Is database access a dealbreaking bottleneck of your webapp?

Comment: I think this question is too vague. What are you concerned about? Extra queries against the database? User's session data being most up to date? Time performance? How are your sessions saved? What is your database setup? What data are you storing in the User object? What are the constraints on your auth/auth system? There just isn't anything to answer right now.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to have a serialized object that will contain a unique identifier to let you get further information later. But, in this object, I would keep information that are used frequently like the username if it's displayed on every pages. Try to keep data in the session as small as possible.